# "Taking back books from people that/which have borrowed them"?

Tags: word-choice

I am not sure which word would be more grammatically correct, "**that**" or "**which**", in this specific sentence:

> "What is a librarian? It may be a person who sits at a little desk, talking in a very low voice and taking back books from people **that**/**which** have borrowed them".

Comment: Shouldn't it be *whom* ?

Comment: No, it certainly should not be _whom_. _Whom_ is used (if it is used) when it is _not_ functioning as the subject of the verb; but the relative is the subject of "have borrowed".

Answer (score 5):

In modern English, relative *which* is not usually used of people. Either *who* or *that* will do fine. I would use *who*.

Comment: Yes as you are talking about a person , I would use 'who'.